How To Seach file names contain any digit/number In windws explorer,? Or file name contain digits/numbers fall between given numbered range?
I searched on the web & also tried below mentioned linked pages, but I did not get the solution.
In Windows Explorer, how to search files whose Names contain any digits or numbers? Or does the file name contain digits/numbers within the given range?
How do I do a search from Windows Explorer for numbers in filename?
How do I do a search from Windows Explorer for numbers in filename?
As per the last link above, we must have put hard-coded numbers to search.
For example, if we type in a search box like Filename:~="88" (numbers Hard Coded), the search result displays all files that have 88 in their name, but if we want to search for any number, like filename:~="###" (if single '#' represent any single Number), the result shows all files which have literal ### in the name.
Also, try filename~="###" but no success.
Another issue is how to search files that have numbers within a given particular range of numbers like Filename:~="2..7"? (~ means Contain)
After studying Advanced Query Syntax & other sources, there are not any symbols or operators available to use that represent any number.
Though "?" handles any single alphabet, number & special character, when required only a number or digit, there are no available symbols for that.
How to find files, and names that contain numbers that fall between particular given numbered ranges? like Filename:=~"5..9" (May be Double Dot for a range between From..To don't know the exact syntax)

Your question is not clear. I have removed the signature and the request for help, which is necessary since you are asking a question.  Due to the clarity of the question, I am unable to fix the numerous formatting and grammatical errors that exist. The grammatical error are a major source of the clarity issues with your question.

Use multiple explicit conditions involving the digits that you want to find. For example, for digits 1, 2, and 3:
System.FileName:~~1 OR System.FileName:~~2 OR System.FileName:~~3

This says, "the file name contains 1 OR the file name contains 2 OR the file name contains 3".
As for finding a range of whole numbers, e.g. 500 through 600, this does not seem to be possible using Windows Search. I recommend FileLocator Pro instead, which supports regular expressions.

Your kind effort is very useful & also work But can we use [0-9] instead of hard coded each number?

You're welcome. Sadly, I can't find any way to use a number range within the file name. 0..9 works with file size, but not with names.

Just for knowledge , can you explain reason for use double unary (tiled) in your answer? hope there are some sources that can deeply explain there,

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax both ~~ and ~= mean "contains." So you could also write it as System.FileName:~=1

Microsoft needs to implement its search features as 3 categories (1) User can Search for Only  Numbers in filenames within a specifically defined range & needs generic symbols / Operator that represent any digit or number. For example, #  (2) Need operator/ Symbol for search Special Characters, handle only special characters without alphabets & numbers  (3) Need Robust "Between" Operator that should find any digits between given numbered range, any alphabets between alphabet range, & special characters  given between specific range like for example filename:~"b..e" (Double Dot)
